# OpenFileDialog box with multiselect, .filenames receiving same name multiple times

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a multi-select `OpenFileDialog` box (named `GetFiles`) that loops through all the selected files and displays their path in a listbox.  Problem is, when all the files are selected and added, it displays the same filename.  Here is all the code:

```
if (GetFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     foreach (string filename in GetFile.FileNames)
     {
          FileNameList.Items.Add(GetFile.FileName);       
     }
```

I feel like there is something really simple that I'm missing....any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are adding the same filename each time using `GetFile.FileName`. You need to use your variable `filename`:

```
if (GetFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 foreach (string filename in GetFile.FileNames)
 {
      FileNameList.Items.Add(filename);       
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're using `GetFile.FileName` when adding to the list rather than the enumerated value `filename`.

Try this instead:

```
if (GetFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    foreach (string filename in GetFile.FileNames) {
        FileNameList.Items.Add(filename);       
    }
}
```